# obtener el dato de un app.config especificamente del listeners del trace

Tags: c#, app.config

Necesito obtener la ruta que esta en el InitialData de mi app.config

```
        <sharedListeners>
        <add initializeData="c:\software\app_messages.svclog" 
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
            <filter type="" />
        </add>
    </sharedListeners>
```

string LogPathFile = <> app_messages.svclog
como realizo esto?

**ACTUALIZACION**
Aca publico todo el app.config

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  
    <system.diagnostics>
      
      
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning,ActivityTracing">
                <listeners>
                    <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                    <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
                        <filter type="" />
                    </add>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add initializeData="c:\software\app_messages.svclog" 
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </sharedListeners>
        <trace autoflush="true" />
    </system.diagnostics>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
      <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging      
          logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
          logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false"
          logMalformedMessages="true"
          logEntireMessage="true"
          maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65535000"
          maxMessagesToLog="500" />
      </diagnostics>
  
    </system.serviceModel>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: podrias publicar app.config completo? porque si este tag "sharedListeners" es una seccion se puede obtener usando el ConfigurationManager, no necesitas parsear ningun xml

Comment: @LeandroTuttini "se puede obtener usando el ConfigurationManager" hola SI!! eso es lo que necesito sin parsear todo o ningun XML!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo Resolví obteniendo el path donde esta el config de mi app
y luego usando linq lo puede encontrar!!

```
      string ConfigFilePath = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None).FilePath;


        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(ConfigFilePath);

        string RutaSvclog = doc.Descendants("add").Where(x => x.Attribute("initializeData") != null).Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("initializeData")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es obtener el valor de *initializeData* puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
string logFileName="";

//Defiminimos un objeto XMLDocument y cargamos el archivo de configuración.
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

//Filtramos al nodo que queremos, en este caso <sharedListeners>
XmlNode xnodes = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/system.diagnostics/sharedListeners");

//Recorremos sus nodos hasta encontrar el <add>
foreach (XmlNode xnn in xnodes.ChildNodes)
{
    if (xnn.Name == "add")
    {
        //Recorremos los atributos hasta encontrar initializeData
        foreach(var att in xnn.Attributes)
        {
            var a= att as XmlAttribute;
            if (a != null)
            {
                if (a.Name == "initializeData")
                {
                    //store file path in the variable
                    logFileName = a.Value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(logFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria uses las clase de configuracion y no xml para acceder al dato,
algo como esto

```
ConfigurationSection diagnosticsSection = (ConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.diagnostics");
ConfigurationElementCollection listeners = diagnosticsSection.ElementInformation.Properties["sharedListeners"].Value as ConfigurationElementCollection; 

foreach (ConfigurationElement listener in listeners)
{
    string initializeData= listener.ElementInformation.Properties["initializeData"].Value.ToString();
}
```

este caso es solo un ejemplo en donde se obtiene la propiedad para ver si de esta forma puedes llegar al dato